# CakePHP: How to update multiple records at the same time with the Form helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

On an edit page for the model Test I want to be able to update the "Questions.order" field on all of it's associated (by hasMany) questions from the same form.

I've ready the [Cake book chapter on saveMany()/saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) in the book, and I'm using the `Model.0.field syntax` but I can't figure out how to tell CakePHP *which* record to corresponds to *which* input. Should the `#` in `Model.#.field` correspond to the question's id field? Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
 echo $this->Form->create( 'Question', array('action'=>'order'));

$n = 0;
foreach ($questions_array as $question) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Question.'.$n.'.order' ); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Question.'.$n.'.id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$question['Question']['id']) ); ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
...
$n++;
endforeach;
$this->Question->Form->end();
```

The form submits and appears to save, but the updated `order` values do not correspond to the right question records. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

Here is the `order` action in my controller:

```
public function admin_order() {
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $this->Question->saveAll($data['Question']);
    $this->Session->setFlash( "Order saved.");
    $this->redirect( $this->referer() );
}
```

Comment: Are you incrementing $n?

Comment: What is "Qset" and how does it fit in with your described question?

Comment: Dave has some good questions, also I see that your form contains a 'submit' button on *every row* (this shouldn't be a problem, just noticed it). Could you [edit] your question and add your controller-code as well, to see 'how' you're saving your data

Comment: @Dave I am incrementing $n, and sorry about the confusion with "Qset". That is the actual name of my class, but I meant to replace it with Question to make it more clear. It was a copy/paste error, which I just corrected.

Comment: @thaJeztah: Yes I intentionally include a submit button next to each input (because the form may be very long). I just updated the question with the controller code. Thanks

Comment: In your updated question, you're using `$question['Qset']['id']`, shouldn't that be `$question['Question']['id']`? Same in your `Form->create('Qset')`? Finally, should the last line just be `echo $this->Form->end()`?

Comment: @thaJeztah: Sorry again. ALL references to Qset should be Question. I was trying to make things clearer by renaming them for the question but it backfired. I think I got all of them fixed now.

Comment: I've tried to explain CakePHP's workings in my answer, just wondering if this explains your question, or is your code not working?

Comment: @thaJeztah My code still isn't working. I think I understand your answer, but I think I'm already doing what you described. The `id` in the hidden value isn't the same because it's a key of whichever `$question` the loop is on.

Comment: Is it updating/doing anything at all? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @thaJeztah I just checked the db and it appears that all three values *are* getting saved to the right records, but for some reason only the first input is rendered in the view with the correct value. The others are empty.

Comment: Inputs created by the FormHelper are filled with values inside `$this->request->data`. You can manually fill that data with data from the database via your model. Otherwise, just set the 'value' of each input inside the loop; the same as you already did with the 'id' input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP associates all fields with the same 'index' to be a single 'record' in your database. The 'index' (i.e. the `0` in `Foo.0.id`) does *not* have any relation to the 'id' of the record, it's just a number.

For example;

```
Foo.0.id   = 123
Foo.0.name = 'hello';
Foo.1.id   = 124
Foo.1.name = 'world';
```

As mentioned in the start of my answer, the index itself does not matter, this code will do *exactly* the same:

```
Foo.12345.id   = 123
Foo.12345.name = 'hello';
Foo.54321.id   = 124
Foo.54321.name = 'world';
```

As long as fields of the *same* record have the *same* 'index', CakePHP will understand that they belong 'together'.

When submitting this data and saving it using;

```
$this->Foo->saveMany($this->data['Foo']); // Just $this->data will probably work as well
```

CakePHP update two rows via the `Foo` model;

table 'foos';

```
id     name
------------------------
123    hello
124    world
```

Your code seems to use the *same* 'id' (`$qset['Qset']['id']`) for each row, which is probably not the right ID to update those records

Comment: After reviewing your answer and my code, I still don't understand how/why CakePHP knows which value to assign to `$this->Form->input('Question.'.$n.'.order' );` My understanding is that `$n` is used to "batch" inputs into single records, but how does CakePHP know which row in the database corresponds to `$n`?

Comment: @Emerson it knows which record to update based on the 'id' field; `Foo.0.id = 123` and `Foo.0.name = 'hello'` will therefore do something like `UPDATE foos SET name='hello' WHERE id = 123;`

Comment: I did an experiment. I added `'value' => $question['Question']['order']` to the options array for the input and now all the values appear correctly. Not sure why that made a difference.

Comment: Just saw your comment above. That seemed to do it. Thanks! Is it surprising that it was necessary to do that? I'm used to Cake knowing the input's value automatically.

Comment: It will know the right values based on `$request->data`, which is filled with the posted data if you submit the form. If no form was posted, you should fill it with data from the database; e.g `$this->request->data = $this->Foo->find('all');` or something similar. however, **only** do this if the form has *not* been posted

Comment: I was talking about in the view. It seems like the controller was saving correctly all along. I was wondering why the form helper seemed to require me to overtly set the value.

Comment: Yup, I understood, however, `$this->request` inside the controller is a reference to the **same** request object that is used inside your view. To demonstrate, try this inside your controller: `$this->request->data['hello'] = 'world';` and this in your view: `echo $this->request['hello'];`. That data is used by the FormHelper to automatically fill the values of your inputs. If the request-object contains the data in the right format, you don't have to set each inputs value manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
As we can see at CakePHP Book, the instruction is:

// Create: id isn't set or is null
$this->Recipe->create();
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);

// **Update**: id is set to a numerical value
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);
```

> Considering there are still people looking for this answer in 2014
>   You must use in the
>   **View**: /* (considering the $n counter)*/ 
>  $this->input('Question.'.$n.'.order');
>   $this->input('Question.'.$n.'.id');
>   **Controller**: $this->Question->updateAll->($this->request->data['Question']);